# What is a proper way to write this headline!

Tags: word-choice, word-request, word-meaning, verbs

> A full curfew/lockdown executed/implemented/applied in Iraq last midnight, and it will continue for 10 days.

Is it **curfew** or **lockdown**? Because pharmacies, food, and grocery stores are allowed to open. Is it **executed, implemented, or applied**? What is the difference between all of them?

Answer (score 2):

A *curfew* usually applies to a limited number of hours in a day, for example, dusk to dawn, or 11 PM to 6 AM.
A *lockdown* could last all day, everyday until lifted.

If some stores are allowed to remain open, presumably their customers are allowed to patronize them. That would be some sort of limited lockdown, with exceptions that would have to be published.

*Implemented* and *applied* seem more likely than *executed*. Another possibility: *put in place*.  *Implemented* suggests that steps were taken to establish the rule, while *applied* doesn't focus on steps; but that is looking for fine distinctions that a writer may not pay attention to.

Comment: I agree, "curfew" means specifically a restriction on the *times* that certain things can be done (most often, that people are not allowed to leave their homes at all during certain hours, but it can be applied to other things).  I would be momentarily confused if I read something using the word "curfew" to mean anything that wasn't about times of day.

Answer (score 1):

> A full curfew/lockdown executed/implemented/applied in Iraq last midnight, and it will continue for 10 days.

The choices you have listed for their respective areas are only slightly different and are fine to use. Publishers usually prefer shorter words and could say

> 10-day Iraq curfew began last midnight

Actual related headlines from some agencies show that both *curfew* and *lockdown* are used.

> Iraq announces 10-day lockdown amid virus surge

> COVID-19: Iraq announces strict, 10-day curfew